# Issues with links in fullscreen code mode on iOS App

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

On Stack Exchange, you can embed links (and other HTML elements) inside code blocks by using `<pre><code>ABC</code></pre>`. This way, you can use `<a>` to create hyperlinks in them:

```html
<pre><code>Take me to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a> please!</code></pre>
```

```
Take me to Stack Overflow please!
```

1. They have different styles in normal and fullscreen code view. Normally, they appear in a light-ish blue and not underlined. In fullscreen mode they appear blue and underlined. This look should be made consistent.

   [image]
   [image]
2. Links cannot be interacted with in fullscreen mode (it just behaves like it was normal text, nothing opens, no visual effects), while they can in normal mode (the website opens)

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.3.3 (Build 13G34)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.7.

Incidentally, some internal changes I made had already fixed this but would cause links to things like questions to open in the popup, which is not ideal.  For simplicity, links in code popups will always open in the preferred browser.